# DockerHub API: List ongoing builds

Tags: rest, api, docker, curl, dockerhub

I am trying to fetch data from DockerHub from this URL using the API:

```
https://cloud.docker.com/u/{account}/repository/docker/{account}/{app}/builds
```

However, the equivalent API URL is invalid. It returns 404:

```
https://cloud.docker.com/v2/repositories/{account}/{app}/builds/
```

On the other hand, the following URL is a valid, but it is not listing the ongoing builds:

```
https://cloud.docker.com/v2/repositories/{account}/{app}/tags/
```

Overall, what I would like to do is to get, from the API, the list of images being built in DockerHub. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this API to list the builds.

```
https://cloud.docker.com/v2/repositories/{account}/{app}/buildhistory/
```

Then append the `build_code` of a build to see the full detail.

```
https://cloud.docker.com/v2/repositories/{account}/{app}/buildhistory/{build_code}
```

I'm not aware of any official documentation for these endpoints. In the past I've used the following source code as a reference.

https://github.com/RyanTheAllmighty/Docker-Hub-API/blob/master/src/api.js